# Recovered Messages Mailboxes. How to get rid of

Tags: mail.app

The Recovered Messages mailboxes  in "On My Mac" com.apple.Mail.Backup should be safe to delete. When I use "delete mailbox" option they do not delete, nothing happens. The mailboxes are empty I do not want them left  there. How can I get rid of them and will it do any damage or create a problem somewhere else ?